# All Checkboxes prop checked but I only want ONE checkbox to be triggered

Tags: jquery, checkbox, prop

I have list of items that can be "add to favorite", in this case I use checkbox, so user can check the checkbox to add to favorite, and vice versa, uncheck the checkbox to remove from favorite.

The flow suppose to be like this:

1. When the checkbox is unchecked, and user click on it, it will be checked
2. When the checkbox is checked, and user click on it, it will trigger a modal which ask them to confirm if they really want to remove the item from favorite. In the pop up modal, there is a confirm button, and when user click on it, it will uncheck the checkbox and close the pop up modal.

Below are the html element

```
    <div class="star_wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" /><label onclick="confirmLabelRemove(this)"><label>
    </div>
    i put the click event in label to trigger the input before it to be checked or unchecked
```

Below are the code to generate the unique ID for each checkbox

```
    var listItems = $(".star_wrap"); // the container of each checkbox
    listItems.each(function (idx) {
    $(this).find('input').attr('id', 'chkbox' + idx);
    //$(this).find('label').attr('for', 'chkbox' + idx); I don't want this 
    feature because If I click on the label it will prop check the 
    checkbox before the pop up modal show up.
});
```

Below are the code to trigger prop check event

```
    function confirmLabelRemove(obj) {
    var thisLabelInput = $(obj).prev(); // find the input before the label

    if ($(thisLabelInput).is(':checked')) {
    overlayConfirmShow(); // transparent layer to prevent back content clickable
    $('.confirmation_box').addClass('show'); // show the pop up modal

    $('#confirmBoxConfirm').on('click', function () {
        $(obj).prev().prop('checked', false);
        $(obj).closest('.grid-item').addClass('unfav');
        overlayConfirmHide();
        $('.confirmation_box').removeClass('show');
     });
    } else {
      $(obj).closest('.grid-item').removeClass('unfav');
      $(obj).prev().prop('checked', true);
     }
    }
```

If there is only 1 checkbox, it works perfectly fine. But when they are a list of checkboxes, Unchecking and checking 1 of the checkbox will trigger previously checked or unchecked checkboxes. Please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually attaching more than one handler to the click event when this line is run more than once (`$('#confirmBoxConfirm').on('click', function () {`) and they are not removed. It means on click, each handler previously set will run.

You can try removing it first:

```
$('#confirmBoxConfirm').off('click').on('click', function () {
```

or if you already have other click handlers on it and want to remove only this one, it has to be a named function:

```
function theClick() {
    $(obj).prev().prop('checked', false);
    $(obj).closest('.grid-item').addClass('unfav');
    overlayConfirmHide();
    $('.confirmation_box').removeClass('show');
};

$('#confirmBoxConfirm').off('click', theClick).on('click', theClick);
```

Comment: The off('click') part is actually to detach those previously attached click event, I see, this actually solve the problem, thank you Kaddath. You saved my day!